# Bounds and Frame Size of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, tvos, bounds

I need some help to set the bounds and frame of a UIView, I change it to a "full screen mode" by changing the bounds to **"0.0f, 0.0f, 1920.0f, 1080.0f"**, that works, the problem I'm having is when I need to reverse the UIView back to the original bounds and frame size, but I'm having trouble setting this up. Can I get some help please?

```
CGRect rect = self.glView.frame;

            if (!CGRectEqualToRect(self.view.frame, rect))
            {
                NSLog(@"Switching to Full Screen now...");

                UIView *image = [_avplayController drawableView];

                image.frame =  CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1920.0f, 1080.0f);

                self.glView.frame = image.frame;

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Switching to Normal Screen...");


                NSLog(@"Old Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.glView.frame));
                NSLog(@"Old Center %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.glView.center));

                // New Bounds and Frame size
                CGRect frame = self.glView.bounds;
                frame.size.height = 927.0f;
                frame.size.width = 619.0f;
                frame.origin.x = 931.0f;
                frame.origin.y = 65.0f;
                self.glView.bounds = frame;

                NSLog(@"New Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.glView.frame));
                NSLog(@"New Center %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.glView.center));

            }
```

Comment: you can see a difference between bound and frame here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `Frame` instead of `Bounds`

```
CGRect frame = self.glView.frame;
frame.size.height = 927.0f;
frame.size.width = 619.0f;
frame.origin.x = 931.0f;
frame.origin.y = 65.0f;
self.glView.frame = frame;
```

The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its **own coordinate system** (0,0).

The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the **superview** it is contained within.

So, frame will help you to adjust your view within superview.

Thanks

Comment: The bounds now seem to work, but the height and width is still incorrect

Comment: @AJ152 Have you replaced my code ? At both places, frame instead of bounds. It's working at my end

Comment: Yes I replaced the entire section of the code, it is funny, I'm running a NSLog to check on the Frame and the results look correct, but in the app the Width and Height did not change, I know you're not seeing the entire code but any idea where I could look on a case like this? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what happened, but after restarting Xcode now it is working. thanks.